# Python - strange list behavior - one variable name, different reference?

Tags: python, list

I'm  a Java, C++, C programmer trying to learn Python. While playing with some code I encountered this weird behavior. I'm somewhat familiar with non statically typed languages, but can't come up with a solution or explanation to this phenomenon.

```
for i in range(3):   
    div(a,b,c,list)
    #print(list)
    list = []
    #print(list)
    printABC(a,b,c)
    theInput = input("\nselect the column: a, b or c : \n")
    if "a" in theInput:         
        list = b + a + c
    elif "b" in theInput:
        list = a + b + c
    elif "c" in theInput:
        list = a + c + b
    print(list);
```

The variable or "name" `list` is a list of numbers, I'm dividing that list into three more lists (`a`, `b` and `c`). Then I clear `list` and repopulate it with a predetermined combination of (`a`, `b` and `c`).

In the first pass of the loop, `list` gets cleared, but by the second pass of the for loop `list = []` is making reference to another completely different variable and not clearing my `list`.

Does anyone have an explanation as of why this is happening?

Comment: Don't name your variables the same thing as [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: To complement and be explicit about what @Mitch said above: you tried naming your variable `list`. Well, `list` is actually a built-in class name, and it is bad practice to rename built-ins. Try something like `my_list` or even `array`.

Comment: yes, one variable (bad) name, different reference at each iteration.

Comment: This works pretty much the same way it would in Java. Not the way it'd work in C++, but Java behaves pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the commenters already said, don't name the variables after built-ins. This Pythoncode should do the trick:

```
a, b, c, = 0, 1, 2
list_1 = [0, 1, 2]
try:
    for i in range(3):   
        a, b, c, = list_1[0], list_1[1], list_1[2]
        print("a:%d, b:%d. c:%d" % (a,b,c))
        theInput = raw_input("\nselect the column: a, b or c : \n")
        if theInput.find("a") > -1:         
            list_1 = [b, a, c]
        elif theInput.find("b") > -1:
            list_1 = [a, b, c]
        elif theInput.find("c") > -1:
            list_1 = [a, c, b]
        print(list_1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The try/except block isn't nessesary, but it was in the code I used as a example.

Comment: Why not keep the `if 'a' in theInput` line instead of the `str.find` method that's arguably much less intuitive?

Comment: @not_a_robot, you right, 'if "a" in theInput' is more intuitive, like I said, I already had the similar example code ready.